# Can't get flex box items to wrap in 2 columns set-up

Tags: css, flexbox

I know this question has been asked several times and the solution is flex-wrap: wrap but for some reason this doesnt work in my code.

Could anyone briefly help me why my divs aren't wrapping?

I basically need always 2 divs next to eachother in a row and then to wrap.

**JSFIDDLE:** [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/AlphaX/wyxeL0kv/16/)

```css
    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -moz-box;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .box {
      flex: 50%;
      text-align: center;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      color: #8988DB;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
  
    <div class="box"><br>Valerian Root</div>
    <div class="box"><br>Lavender</div>
    <div class="box"><br>Lemon Balm</div>
    <div class="box"><br>Chamomile</div>
    <div class="box"><br>Passion Flower</div>
    <div class="box"><br>Hops</div>
    <div class="box"><br>Rooibos</div>
    <div class="box"><br>Cinnamon</div>
    
  </div>
```

Thanks so much!

Alpha

Comment: Note, it is useless with prefixed properties like `display: -ms-flexbox;` on the parent, when you don't use it for the child's properties, e.g. `flex: 50%`. Furthermore, `flex-wrap: wrap` on the child won't apply anything as it is a _"flex parent" (in your case the `wrapper`)_ property.

Comment: thanks so much for clarifying that! I'm still learning my way around - much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a note, in the CSS rule for the flex container, place the regular `display: flex` property *after*  all the prefix-versions.

For it to work also in IE11, use `width: 50%` instead of `flex: 50%`, combined with `box-sizing: border-box`, where *borders/padding* gets included in the set width.

```css
.wrapper {
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .box {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 50%;
      padding: 0 30px 10px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #8988DB;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  
    <div class="box"><br>Valerian Root</div>
    <div class="box"><br>Lavender</div>
    <div class="box"><br>Lemon Balm</div>
    <div class="box"><br>Chamomile</div>
    <div class="box"><br>Passion Flower</div>
    <div class="box"><br>Hops</div>
    <div class="box"><br>Rooibos</div>
    <div class="box"><br>Cinnamon</div>
    
  </div>
```

Comment: Up to you but I've already done that so you'll just be repeating the information in my answer.

Comment: I did made an edit...hopefully one you can accept :) ...and an upvote to compensate for the, IMHO, wrong downvote

Comment: @Paulie_D Made an edit here...which made it more clear and separated from your answer, and hopefully, assuming you downvoted this, such downvote could be retracted.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think the real issue was indeed the placement of display: flex after the other prefixes! Never thought this could cause such an issue - will definitely keep this one in mind! Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @AlphaX The main reason is `box-sizing: border-box`, the order of prefixed properties can cause issues, though not, in reality, as much as the former.

Answer (score 2):

Step into [CSS Grid](https://cssgrid.io/), it's ideal for this use case. Your use case is so simple, you only need three lines of CSS to pull it off.

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; // creates two responsive columns
  grid-gap: 10px; // puts 10px between each node in the grid
}
```

Comment: I actually thought first about using a grid but then went back to flex, should have taken a grid! Thanks - cant believe how easy it is!!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all you need is a proper CSS reset, specifically, the `box-sizing` property so that borders are not included in the `width` calculations.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  flex: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #8988DB;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="box"><br>Valerian Root</div>
  <div class="box"><br>Lavender</div>
  <div class="box"><br>Lemon Balm</div>
  <div class="box"><br>Chamomile</div>
  <div class="box"><br>Passion Flower</div>
  <div class="box"><br>Hops</div>
  <div class="box"><br>Rooibos</div>
  <div class="box"><br>Cinnamon</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! this worked as well!